# Gson custom deserializer is never called by retrofit2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 to make REST APIS calls
the date-time format received from server is ISO 8601 offset time zone format like this
 `"CycleStartTime": "2021-06-08T08:38:09+02:00",`

I am trying to convert this to LocalDateTime using GsonConverter as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486417/10138208).

I created the custom deserialization

```kotlin
class LocaleDateTimeDeserializer:JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>{
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): LocalDateTime {
        try {
            Log.d("LocaleDateTimeDes",json.asJsonPrimitive.asString)
            if (typeOfT == LocalDateTime::class.java) {

                val offsetTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(json.asJsonPrimitive.asString)
                Log.d("LocaleDateTimeDes",offsetTime.toString())
                return  offsetTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw JsonParseException(e)
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown type: $typeOfT")
    }

}
```

and that's how I build retrofit object

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime::class.java,LocaleDateTimeDeserializer()).create()
   
retrofitBuilder.client(HttpClient.createClient(context))
          .baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build()
```

But whenever that get request is made that contains the Time the deserialize method is never called and  I get this error
`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 7 column 36 path $.Catalogs[0].CycleInfo.CycleStartTime`

The data class is working fine because when i change the type of this field to String instead of LocalDateTime، I have no issues

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @AshikurRahman sadly, no